# Reading Dual/Multiple Properties in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties, spring-boot

I'm trying to read the application specific properties from database, and I'm trying to keep the database credentials in properties file.

> So I need to load both properties (File and DB), while the application is
>   loading.

I'm having my configuration as follows.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="WEB-INF/config/db.properties"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="properties">
        <bean class="org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationConverter" factory-method="getProperties">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.apache.commons.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration">
                    <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="postgresqlDataSource"/>
                    <constructor-arg value="TBL_APP_SETTINGS"/>
                    <constructor-arg value="PROP_KEY"/>
                    <constructor-arg value="PROP_VALUE"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="postgresqlDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.pass}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="5"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="5000"/>
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="30000"/>
    <property name="minIdle" value="3"/>
</bean>
```

It's throwing error for ${db.url}

please help how to do this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to externalize some of your config properties the guide is on  [spring.io site](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). You can pass properies as java system properties or command line arguments

The second way is to write your own PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer which will read properties from application.yml and from the database

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way you can do it is writing credentials into the spring xml and import it to your main xml and reference them as beans:

```
<bean id="dbUrl" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="jdbc://..."/>
</bean>
... same for dbUser and dbPassword
```

And then refer to the value using `ref`.